# Overloaded operator issue C++

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I am having an issue with an overloaded operator that does not seem to be working right. The following is my code.

ACCOUNT.H

```
#ifndef SICT_ACCOUNT_H__
#define SICT_ACCOUNT_H__

#include <iostream>

#define MAX_NAME 40

namespace sict
{
    class Account
    {
        char name_[MAX_NAME+1];
        double balance_;
    public:
        Account();
        Account(double);
        Account(const char*, double = 0.0);
        void display(bool = true) const;
        Account& operator=(const Account&);
        Account& operator+=(const Account&);
        friend Account operator+(Account&, const Account&);
    };
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Account& a);
};

#endif
```

ACCOUNT.CPP

```
 #include <cstring>
 #include <iomanip>
 #include "Account.h"

namespace sict
{
    Account::Account()
    {
        name_[0] = '\0';
        balance_ = 0;
    }

    Account::Account(double balance)
    {
        name_[0] = '\0';
        balance_ = balance;
    }

    Account::Account(const char name[], double balance)
    {
        name_[MAX_NAME] = '\0';
        strncpy(name_, name, MAX_NAME);
        balance_ = balance;
    }

    void Account::display(bool gotoNewline) const
    {
        std::cout << (name_[0] ? name_: "No Name") << ": $" << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << balance_;
        if(gotoNewline)
        {
          std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Account& a)
    {
      a.display();
      return os;
    }

    Account& Account::operator=(const Account& c)
    {
      balance_ = c.balance_;
      name_[MAX_NAME] = '\0';
      strncpy(name_, c.name_, MAX_NAME);

      return *this;
    }

    Account& Account::operator+=(const Account& b)
    {
      balance_ += b.balance_;
      return *this;
    }

    Account operator+(Account& a, const Account& b)
    {
      return a.balance_ + b.balance_;
    }


}
```

MAIN

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Account.h"

using namespace sict;

void displayABC(const Account& a, const Account& b, const Account& c)
{
    std::cout << "A: " << a << std::endl << "B: " << b << std::endl
    << "C: " << c << std::endl << "--------" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Account a;
    Account b("Saving", 10000.99);
    Account c("Checking", 100.99);
    displayABC(a, b, c);
    a = b + c;
    displayABC(a, b, c);
    a = "Joint";
    displayABC(a, b, c);
    a = b += c;
    displayABC(a, b, c);
    a = b += c += 100.01;
    displayABC(a, b, c);

    return 0;
}
```

the output that I am supposed to get is

```
A: No Name: $0.00
B: Saving: $10000.99
C: Checking: $100.99
--------
A: No Name: $10101.98
B: Saving: $10000.99
C: Checking: $100.99
--------
A: Joint: $10101.98
B: Saving: $10000.99
C: Checking: $100.99
--------
A: Saving: $10101.98
B: Saving: $10101.98
C: Checking: $100.99
--------
A: Saving: $10302.98
B: Saving: $10302.98
C: Checking: $201.00
```

this is the out that I am getting now

```
A: No Name: $0.00
B: Saving: $10000.99
C: Checking: $100.99
--------
A: No Name: $10101.98
B: Saving: $10000.99
C: Checking: $100.99
--------
A: Joint: $0.00
B: Saving: $10000.99
C: Checking: $100.99
--------
A: Saving: $10101.98
B: Saving: $10101.98
C: Checking: $100.99
--------
A: Saving: $10302.98
B: Saving: $10302.98
C: Checking: $201.00
--------
```

As you can see the integer value is 0 for the display :

A: Joint: $0.00.

I cannot seem to figure this out. any help is appreciated!

Comment: `a = "Joint";` What should happens on this line?

Comment: that uses the the = operator and adds the name "Joint" to the current object.

Comment: @a-one -- your answer to the comment suggest that you've done no real debugging.  You should have seen that `a` becomes reset as soon as that line was executed.  Then your question would have been asked with a more focused situation, i.e.  "Why is my object being reset when I execute this line?", and not just "overloading is not working right".   Debugging is something that you must learn to do, as it is part and parcel of learning how to write programs.

Comment: Your friend `operator+()` ought to have both arguments `const T&` (or pass the first one by value and use `+=` on the copy)

Comment: ok I understand, I am a second semester student for what its worth and did not realize that. I will use a debugger in the future. I was suggested that last time as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
displayABC(a, b, c);
a = b + c;
displayABC(a, b, c);
a = "Joint"; //The Problem!!
displayABC(a, b, c);
a = b += c;
displayABC(a, b, c);
a = b += c += 100.01;
displayABC(a, b, c);
```

You haven't defined a specific `operator=` for string objects, and as a result, the compiler is substituting in the Constructor `Account(const char name[], double balance = 0.0)`, which because there's no balance specified, is setting the balance to 0.

You should add the keyword `explicit` to the Constructor to prevent it from doing that, or add an additional overload to allow the name to be set without altering the balance.

```
explicit Account::Account(const char name[], double balance)
{
    name_[MAX_NAME] = '\0';
    strncpy(name_, name, MAX_NAME);
    balance_ = balance;
}
```

By the way, in c++ world, you should replace any and all references of type `const char *` with `std::string`, and store the same in your objects. The only time you should ever use c-string is if you have to interface with a c-library.

Comment: He should add `explicit` to constructors, not assigment operator.

Comment: Hi I added explicit and got this error  Account.cpp:41:18: error: expected unqualified-id
        Account& explicit Account::operator=(const Account& c)

Comment: @a-one @revolver_ocelot I made the edit. I could have sworn `explicit` was valid for operator overloads, but apparently not.

Comment: i added it to the constructor and received this 'explicit' can only be specified inside the class
      definition

Comment: ok will definitely take that into consideration for the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = "Joint";
```

is in fact

```
a = Account("Joint");
```

so

```
a = Account("Joint", 0.0);
```

so reset `a` balance.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting `a` as you told it to.

```
a = "Joint";
```

is equivalent to

```
a = Account("Joint");
```

which creates a new account and uses the assignment operator to assign the newly created `Account` to `a`.

You should mark your constructor as `explicit` and create a setter for the account name.